# modifying legend in excel scatter plot

Tags: excel, legend, scatter-plot

This is my first question in stackoverflow. 
I have a table of data which I plan to plot in a scatter plot as follows

```
    Name     |Competency |Performance  
-------------|-----------|-------------    
    baron    |    1      | 1    
    davis    |    2      | 2    
    dingan   |    2      | 2    
    sarin    |    4      | 1
```

I am plotting the competency score in X axis and performance score in Y axis. I need to name each plot. The data set has close to 200 names. If I name each data point then the graph becomes too cluttered. I am planning to name each data point in the legend which means the name of each data point in the legend shall be taken from a different column i.e name. Please let me know how this can be done. I have attached a screenshot of an example

Regards,
Anup

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

This kind of approach is illustrated here (http://peltiertech.com/double-legend-in-a-single-chart/ )..So the trick is we need to create two graphs in the same sheet. One plot will have name and competency as parameters and the other will have competency and performance as parameters. We hide the legend of the first plot and hide the plot area of the second plot. this can be done by brining in transparency of legend as 0% and putting in solid fill. Nice hack btw. Thanks a lot guys